# How can I determine that the matrix A is nonsingular?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A = I - \frac{1}{x^Tx}xx^T - \frac{1}{y^Tx}yy^T$, I want to show that $A$ is nonsingular. In other words, I want to show that $Az = 0$ only has the trivial solution of $z$ being the zero vector.

All I am given is that $y^Tx < 0$. Thanks for any help!

Comment: second denominator should be $y^T y$ or is correct as written, $y^T x$?

Comment: @gt6989b If the denominator is $y^Ty$, then $x=(1,0)^T$, $y=(0,1)^T$ is a counterexample.

Comment: The denominator should be $y^Tx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $Au = 0$. Then $u = \tfrac{u^Tx}{\|x\|2}x + \tfrac{u^Ty}{\|y\|2}y$. Hence, $u^Tx = u^Tx + \tfrac{(u^Ty)(y^Tx)}{\|y\|^2}$, and therefore $u^Ty = 0$. Similarly, one shows that $u^Tx = 0$. Consequently,
$$
u^Tu = u^T\left(\tfrac{u^Tx}{\|x\|2}x + \tfrac{u^Ty}{\|y\|2}y\right) = \tfrac{u^Tx}{\|x\|2}(u^Tx) + \tfrac{u^Ty}{\|y\|2}(u^Ty) = 0.
$$
Thus, $u=0$.

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Some notations first :

Initial remark : we can consider that we are in $\mathbb{R^n}$, thus vectors can be identified with column matrices.

Set $u=x/\|x\|$ and $v=y/\|y\|$.

These are unit norm vectors with dot product $a:=u^Tv<0$.

Let $A=(u|v)$ be the $n \times 2$ matrix obtained by gathering columns $u$ and $v$.

Our issue is to prove that $I_n-(uu^T+vv^T)=I_n-AA^T$ is nonsingular.

Let us establish it by proving that this matrix has a non zero determinant.

Let us use a classical result :

$$\det(I_n-AA^T)=\det(I_2-A^TA)\tag{1}$$

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_determinant_identity)

Thus we have only to prove that $\det(I_2-A^TA) \neq 0$.

This is easy because $A^TA=\begin{pmatrix}u^Tu&u^Tv\\v^Tu&v^Tv\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&a\\a&1\end{pmatrix}$ with $a=u^Tv<0$.

giving $\det(I_2-A^TA)=\det \begin{pmatrix}0&-a\\-a&0\end{pmatrix}=-a^2 \neq 0.$

Remark : the result holds as well when $u^Tv>0$. The important point is that $u^Tv \neq 0$.